# SharePoint Calculated column based on other List data

Tags: sharepoint, lookup, contains, calculated-columns

Possible to set the value of a calcualted column to data from another list? Say I have a lookup column, and based on my selection, another column from that lookup list?

Also, Does the calculated column offer String Contains or begins with operators?

And, side question, Can either of the above be done inside workflow Alert email conditons?

Thanks.

Comment: These are 3 separate questions - so you would be better putting them in as 3 separate posts.

Comment: Any reason this was closed and not migrated to SharePoint SE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the calculated column offer
>   String Contains or begins with
>   operators?

For contains/begins you can use either SEARCH (case insensitive and allows wildcards) or [FIND](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/windows-sharepoint-services-help/find-function-HA001160996.aspx) (case sensitive)

So for example "Begins With" looking for "First words" in field [Field] would be

```
IF ( FIND("First words",[Field]) == 1, True, False)
```

Comment: found out that you can't use Lookup columns in calculated formulas.

Comment: You didn't make that clear in your 3 questions. you only mentioned lookup columns in the first one. Best to split them out to make clear.

Answer (score 2):

1. I do not know if 2010 offers that ability with calculated columns, but 2007 does not.  However, you could use a workflow to populate a field in the current list from the other list and then create a calcualted column based on that field.
2. Ryan already answered that one.
3. Yes this can be done in workflows but I'd need to know more about what exactly you were trying to do before I could intelligently help.

Comment: Thank you. We have a list with a very long lookup column, something like 200 entries. When the user enters a new row, they get an alert email from a workflow developed in SPD. If they select one of 30 entries in that lookup, we want to include a hyperlink that will have the row id in the query string.  Just want to know if possible with an SPD workflow email.

Answer (score 2):

Are you familiar with looking up ID's in a workflow based on values entered in the list?  If not, let me know and we'll break that out a little further.

Assuming you are, you could create a variable named LookupID and put the Row ID of the lookup value from the Lookup list.  Then analyze the variable value and see if it matches one of the IDs that meet your criteria.

If it does, then build the URL using the Dynamic String builder to include the ID.  So the URL would look something like:

http://server/site/Lists/myList/DispForm.aspx?ID=[ListID]

[ListID] is a parameter that you add to the string using the Lookup Field button in the dynamic string builder.